# Rig leg deformation problem

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

[image]

my rig's leg is not deforming properly it starts making this whenever i try to lift the leg
[image]

I tried using thing thing her but that gave the rig a weird bulge  like thing on its leg when i put it in rest mode

[image]

Comment: You really haven't provided enough info for anyone to help you.

Comment: my bad i forgot to add a link for the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might solve your problem: in your .blend file, move the heads of the "Leg_Top" bones, in the character's armature, upwards and closer together, thus letting the legs pivot from further within the character's geometry.

The original armature leg problem:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the original leg problem]

The selected heads of the Leg_Top bones:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the original heads in edit mode]

The selected heads again, this time moved upwards and closer together:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the modified heads in edit mode]

The result of the previous edit:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the fixed result]

I hope that this solved your problem.